# Is there any datatype or method that calculates the sum of previous array cells in the present cell?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

For example if the given array is

> 1,6,3,2,7.

I want to store it in an array in a way given below:

> 1,7,10,12,19

where a[2]=a[1]+a[2] and so on.

Is there any datatype where i can store in this manner or any methods available to calculate this instead of using a for loop and calculating it.

Comment: Which language do you want this for...C++ or C? They're not the same thing

Comment: "_instead of using a for loop and calculating it_" -- How about a `while` loop?  :p

Comment: You always need a loop for this, be it implicitly or explicitly. Why does that matter to you?

Answer (score 4):

In C++, you may use `std::partial_sum` (inside `<numeric>`):

```
std::vector<int> v{1,6,3,2,7};

std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/nC7rNJ)

Comment: This is also a loop, in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

In c++, one way is to use a transform algorithm with a stateful transform function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main()
{

    // input data
    int source[] = { 1, 6, 3, 2, 7 };

    // buffer for output data
    auto dest = std::array<int, sizeof(source) / sizeof(source[0])> { 0 };

    // transform operation
    std::transform(std::begin(source),
                   std::end(source),
                   std::begin(dest), [tot = 0](auto&& x)  mutable{ return tot += x; });


    // emit results
    std::copy(std::begin(dest), std::end(dest), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

update - in response to loop question

Here's the output from g++ with -O2.

We can see that the entire transformation has been computed at compile time. There is no loop (in this instance).

While this is a corner case (the inputs are immutable and known at compile time) it illustrates a valuable concept - **std::algorithms express intent**, *not implementation*. The compiler and implementation may do what it likes under the covers, provided the interface's guarantees are honoured.

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, 1
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, .L.str
        mov     edx, 2
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, 7
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, .L.str
        mov     edx, 2
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, 10
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, .L.str
        mov     edx, 2
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, 12
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, .L.str
        mov     edx, 2
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, 19
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, .L.str
        mov     edx, 2
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, std::cout
        mov     esi, .L.str.1
        mov     edx, 1
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

Comment: This is also a loop, in disguise.

Comment: @Lundin That will depend on the architecture and the quality of the optimiser. I suspect in the example above, the entire transformation will be performed at compile time and the pre-computed results simply emitted.

However, conceptually I see your point. I cannot imagine it being possible to accumulate a partial sum without iterating across a range.

Comment: @RichardHodges All other loops can be unrolled, too, so even if you code a for-loop, you could say "No loop in this particular case.". But I think we all agree, that in the _general_ case a loop is unavoidable.

Comment: @Ctx yup, not even parallelism can help since each output element is dependent on the previous one.

Comment: @RichardHodges Thinking again, if the items are inserted into the structure strictly in order, it could be calculated on insertion…

Comment: @Ctx That is what the transform, or partial_sum algorithms do.

Comment: @RichardHodges No, these iterate over existant data. I talk about calculating the values on insertion into the data structure, this is different in procedure. Just like the difference of inserting an element sorted into a list or to sort a whole list.

Comment: @Ctx but the algorithm still produces an answer that depends on the previous one. So the algorithm must still be called sequentially - in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

Simply iterate through the array. Use a variable `int previous=0;` which you update each time you assign a value:

```
new_array[i] = old_array[i] + previous;
previous = new_array[i];
```

Comment: This would require a loop, right? OP wants other ways besides using loops.

Comment: @CoolGuy Maybe he can conjure the numbers out of thin air then.